# How can we troubleshoot an Excel Hard Crash with error 0xc0000005 caused by add-in

Tags: excel, vba, crash, excel-addins

We are using an Excel add-in, where on occasion, Excel crashes hard with error 0xc0000005. The error occurs with various versions of Excel. I don't doubt the issue is a problem with the excel add-in but can not figure out how to troubleshoot.

I noticed that there are a few related questions on StackOverflow but have not seen any resolutions or comments that would be useful in troubleshooting.

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.16227.20280, time stamp: 0x64312fdb
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.16227.20280, time stamp: 0x64312fdb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000096bd88
Faulting process id: 0x0x67C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D979C13AEF7AEA
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: 1c5c24f2-6bbc-4bf6-88e5-d9104ae61e6c
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: You are very much on your own here. The support from Microsoft in cases like this is at best "remove the add-in". I have experienced two types of problems like yours. A: The DLLs used by the add-in needed an update B: Another add-in caused it.

Comment: Do you develop a COM add-in for Excel? Which line of code exactly causes Excel crash?